# Giving a matrix as an input to a verilog module

Tags: verilog, decode

I am working with the implementation of a Product Code on FPGA . The product code is basically a matrix with the rows and columns being  codewords coming from a BCH codebase (BCH(1023,993,3)) . I already have a BCH decoder in Verilog . I want to have a 1023 by 1023 matrix as an input to my Product code decoder and then call upon that module to decode the rows and columns of the product code matrix . The way the decoding process works at a higher level is that , if there are more than 3 errors in a codeword , the BCH decoder module fixes those errors and moves to the next row/ column .

The questions I have are as follows :
1) Is it possible to make the input port as a matrix ?
2) If I need to pipeline the decoding process, do I need to instantiate the BCH decoder 1023 times or is there a better way to do it ?
3) If it is not possible to make the input port as a matrix , do I need to give all the 1023 rows as 1-D vectors like input row1[1022:0] or is there a better way to do that ?
4) If the technique mentioned in step 3 is the only one available, how do I make the column vectors out of those row vectors available as the inputs ?

Thanks in advance. I really appreciate your time and effort .

Comment: I assume you know that Verilog code represents hardware. Thus what you want is a module which has an interface with **more then a million wires**. I suggest you look for a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One **can not pass a two dimensional array as a port in Verilog**. SystemVerilog supports 2D array as ports of modules.

Here, you need to take a vector and do some pack/unpack operations. One can define macros for the same.

Here is a sample code where `PACK_ARRAY` macro **packs** two dimensional array into a single vector. Packing is done based on the width and length provided as input. Similarly, `UNPACK_ARRAY` **unpacks** a vector into a two dimensional array.

```
`define PACK_ARRAY(PK_WIDTH,PK_LEN,PK_SRC,PK_DEST) \
genvar pk_idx; \
generate \
  for (pk_idx=0; pk_idx<(PK_LEN); pk_idx=pk_idx+1) \
    begin \
      assign PK_DEST[((PK_WIDTH)*pk_idx+((PK_WIDTH)-1)):((PK_WIDTH)*pk_idx)] = PK_SRC[pk_idx][((PK_WIDTH)-1):0]; \
    end \
endgenerate


`define UNPACK_ARRAY(PK_WIDTH,PK_LEN,PK_DEST,PK_SRC) \
genvar unpk_idx; \
generate \
  for (unpk_idx=0; unpk_idx<(PK_LEN); unpk_idx=unpk_idx+1) begin \
    assign PK_DEST[unpk_idx][((PK_WIDTH)-1):0] = PK_SRC[((PK_WIDTH)*unpk_idx+(PK_WIDTH-1)):((PK_WIDTH)*unpk_idx)]; \
  end \
endgenerate


module example (
  input  [(63):0] pack_4_16_in,
  output [(31):0] pack_16_2_out
    );

wire [3:0] in [0:15];

`UNPACK_ARRAY(4,16,in,pack_4_16_in)

wire [15:0] out [0:1];
`PACK_ARRAY(16,2,in,pack_16_2_out)


// useful code goes here

endmodule // example
```

As suggested in comments, I believe that you should think of **some other approach rather than directly providing 1023*1023 wires as input and output to a single module**. As an alternative, you can provide the 1023*1023 matrix elements **row wise** and **store them into internal memory** of module.

```
module example(
  input [1023:0] inp, // One can take 'load', 'addr' etc as inputs also
  input clk, rst,
  output [1023:0] out
);

reg [1023:0] mem [0:1023];
reg [9:0] cnt;

always @(posedge clk) begin
  mem[cnt] <= inp;
  cnt      <= cnt + 1;
end

// Some other logic
endmodule
```

Here, it will take **1K clocks** to load the memory and some glue logic might be required. But this approach will implement a memory **inside** the module and you will not have hard coded million wires coming as ports.

Refer to [this forum discussion](http://www.edaboard.com/showthread.php?t=80929) for the above code.

Comment: Thank you . I really appreciate your help .